# Question about why a certain element in a strong induction is part of the inductive hypothesis and not the base cases

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

The problem:

Suppose we can reach the first and second rungs of an infinite ladder, and we know that if we can reach a rung, then we can reach two rungs higher. Prove that we can reach every rung using strong induction.

My Question:

In the textbook this problem is from, the solution provided states that for the base cases, we should only assume the fact that we can reach the first rung is the base case
and that the fact we can reach the second rung is part of the inductive step.

But, shouldn't being able to reach the second rung of the ladder also be a base case? What makes it not a part of base cases and part of the inductive step?

Comment: The base case is an answer to the question: can we get on the first rung of the ladder?

Comment: I understand that, but why is reaching the second rung of the ladder also not a base case

Comment: Proving the first goes to the second is the inductive step (somewhat). The inductive step means that any arbitrary rung can be reached.